# I'm trying to add jquery to an offsite widget

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm building a widget for users to add on their websites to chat with people from their website. Now since the script that handles it needs jquery installed I have been attempting to add the jquery source directly in the javascript file to no avail. It just seems that it's not working. I tried this

```
(function(){
var jQuery;

if (window.jQuery === undefined || window.jQuery.fn.jquery !== '1.8.1') {
    var script_tag = document.createElement('script');
    script_tag.setAttribute("type","text/javascript");
    script_tag.setAttribute("src",
        "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.1/jquery.min.js");
    if (script_tag.readyState) {
      script_tag.onreadystatechange = function () { // For old versions of IE
          if (this.readyState == 'complete' || this.readyState == 'loaded') {
              scriptLoadHandler();
          }
      };
    } else {
      script_tag.onload = scriptLoadHandler;
    }
    // Try to find the head, otherwise default to the documentElement
    (document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0] || document.documentElement).appendChild(script_tag);
} else {
    // The jQuery version on the window is the one we want to use
    jQuery = window.jQuery;
    main();
}

/******** Called once jQuery has loaded ******/
function scriptLoadHandler() {
    // Restore $ and window.jQuery to their previous values and store the
    // new jQuery in our local jQuery variable
    jQuery = window.jQuery.noConflict(true);
    // Call our main function
    main(); 
}


function main(){
$(document).ready(function($){

$('.reflap-call').click(function(){
window.location.href = 'http://www.reflap.com/beta/widget/michael';
});
});
}
})();
```

But when I go on any website and add this script

```
<script src="http://www.reflap.com/beta/assets/js/widget.js"></script>
<a href="#" class="reflap-call">Chat</a>
```

The script doesn't work because it seems that the jquery is not properly loaded. The only way I can circumvent it is by using this script

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.reflap.com/beta/assets/js/widget.js"></script>
<a href="#" class="reflap-call">Chat</a>
```

I would like to properly add jquery to the widget.js so I won't have to add a third line when users want to use the script.

Answer (score 1):

Although you can ([manually load jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/950087/how-to-include-a-javascript-file-in-another-javascript-file)) from within your widget, it is better to just add the jQuery  tag, or ask your widget users to add it.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I actually got it to work by commenting out jQuery = window.jQuery.noConflict(true);

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work just by commenting out

```
jQuery = window.jQuery.noConflict(true);
```